# how recursive call work

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote fizzbuzz code by using a recursive call by referencing some code on the internet. Below code works fine but I can't fully understand whats going on when this code is executed.

To be more specific, I can not understand why `1` is displayed at first. in `main()` method, `recurrence()` receives `100`, so it feels `Buzz` (the result of 100) is displayed at first.

I debugged on IntelliJ putting the breakpoint on `recurrence(i - 1)`, that method is called 100 times first and the rest of the code is executed afterward. I wonder where the result of `recuurence` is stored.

```java
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        recurrence(100);
    }

    private static void recurrence(int i) {
        if (i > 1) {
            recurrence(i - 1);
        }

        if (i % 15 == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Buzz");
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Fizz");
        } else
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the printing happens _after the recursion returns_ - so the printing happens when the stack unwinds.

Comment: The best way to understand recursion is to use pen and paper - write down exactly what happens and it will help you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can not understand why 1 is displayed at first. in main() method,

Because the first invocation with `100` makes that the recursive call loops on this conditional statement that is `true` :

```
if (i > 1) {
    recurrence(i - 1);
}
```

It is true for `recurrence(100)`, `recurrence(99)`, `recurrence(98)`, ... until `recurrence(1)`.
At the recursive invocation (`recurrence(1)`) where `i=1`, things are different as the single conditional statement evaluated to `true` is :

```
else
     System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
```

So `1` is printed first.

---

> I understand why 1 is printed first. 1 is the result of recurrence(1),
>   but struggling with understand where the rest of results come from. I
>   try to think about it.

The next output are related to the "unstack" of the currently stacked invocations.

The "unstack" of the invocations is performed in the reverse order of them. 
So you unstack from the last invocation to the first one.

`recurrence(100)`,  `recurrence(99)`,  `recurrence(98)`, ..., 
 `recurrence(2)`, `recurrence(1)` was invoked and stacked 
and the unstack is done from  `recurrence(1)`,  `recurrence(2)`,   ..., 
 `recurrence(100)`.

**To ease how recursive invocation works, remember that method invocations are stacked (recursive or not) and a stack is a  last-in-first-out structure.**

So to come back to the explanation, as  `recurrence(1)` reaches this statement :

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
```

The method returns and the JVM continues with the previous stacked invocation :

`recurrence(2)` that executes the following statements (the previous statements were already invoked):

```
    if (i % 15 == 0) {
        System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Fizz");
    } else
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
```

Like for `recurrence(1)`,  the single conditional statement evaluated to `true` is :

```
else
     System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
```

So `2` is printed.

Go on applying the same logic for currently stacked invocations `recurrence(3)`, `recurrence(4)` until `recurrence(100)` and all should be clear.

Comment: I understand why ```1``` is printed first. ```1``` is the result of ```recurrence(1)```, but struggling with understand where the rest of results come from.  I try to think about it.

Comment: @Rohan Kishibe I edited. Let me know if it is not clear enough.

Comment: the result of ```recurrence(100)```,```recurrence(99)```,```recurrence(98)```,... is stored in `stack` hence the evaluation of each method call is proceded from last stacked element. Your kind explanation helps me to understand how this code work. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

- You call  `recurrence(100);`
- that calls `recurrence(99);` because `100>1`
- that calls `recurrence(98);` because `99>1`
- ...
- that calls `recurrence(1);` because `2>1` -> go to `else` and print `1`
- then all the other prints are made

---

Try to understand with an easier code which will print `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurrence(10);
}

private static void recurrence(int i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        recurrence(i - 1);
    }       
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
}

>recurrence(10) 
  -> recurrence(9) 
    -> recurrence(8) 
      -> recurrence(7) 
        -> recurrence(6)
          -> recurrence(5)
            -> recurrence(4)
              -> recurrence(3)
                -> recurrence(2) 
                  -> recurrence(1) 
                  -> print(1)
                -> print(2)
              -> print(3)
            -> print(4)
          -> print(5) 
        -> print(6)
      -> print(7) 
    -> print(8)
  -> print(9)
-> print(10)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (i > 1) {
        recurrence(i - 1);
    }
```

This statement 'restarts' the method and the code underneath will not be executed untill i > 1 returns false (which first happens when i = 1).

As for where the result is stored: your method is of return type void which means there is no result. If you were thinking about output I hope you now understand why it didn't print.

Answer (score 1):

You got if athe start of your function

```
if (i > 1) {
            recurrence(i - 1);
        }
```

at this place the "next level of recursion" is invoked (that means, that at each level the first thing you do is invoke another recursive function), when you get to the last  level( level 100th -> i=1) you can get to the code

```
if (i % 15 == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Buzz");
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Fizz");
        } else
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

after finising the code, level 100th (i=1) is finished, then is time to level 99th, 98th and the last one who finish the function is level 1 (i = 100).

**try to watch some videos on the internet (how recursion is working) that will explain this on presentation, that will be much easier to understand.**

Comment: try to watch some videos on the internet (how recursion is working) that will explain this on presentation, that will be much easier to understand.